# Function finishes before Promises have ended

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement the actualSendPush function to use in order to send 200 users a push notification, and then handle the result of sendToDevice(). Problem is that even though I wrapped all the async code with Promise, the cloud function still finishes before console.log of the sendToDevice().then execution. Some push notifications also don't reach their destination.

When calling actualSendPush I'm using Promise as well. What is the flaw in this code?

```
function actualSendPush(fcmKey, volId, title, msg, evtId, orgId, url){

const promises = [];

console.log("notifying user about msg ", fcmKey, " ", msg);

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "Help Required",
        body: title,
        sound:"default",
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },
    data: {
            title : title,
            msg : msg,
            eventId : evtId
          }
};

return Promise.all([admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmKey, payload)
    .then(function (response) {


        // event push success counter 
        if (response.successCount == 1)
        {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            promises.push(incrementTransaction("events/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/numEventsSendSuccess"));
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Failed sent message:", response);
            promises.push(incrementTransaction("events/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/numEventsSendFail"));
        }

        /*var updates = {};
        updates["eventUserReqs/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/users/" + volId + "/status"] = response.successCount; // 0 failed 1 success
        admin.database().ref().update(updates);*/

        // The user might have opened the push before the server side had the chance to change the status to successful or not.. if it 
        // already has a value, don't change it.
        var dbRef = admin.database().ref("eventUserReqs/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/users/" + volId + "/status");

        promises.push(dbRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
          return current_value != null ? current_value : (response.successCount);
        }));

        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);

        // event push fail counter
        incrementTransaction("events/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/numEventsSendFail");

        var dbRef = admin.database().ref("eventUserReqs/" + orgId + "/" + evtId + "/users/" + volId + "/status");
        return dbRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
          return current_value != null ? current_value : 0;
        });
    })]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "terminates"? actualSendPush terminates immediately  returning a Promise that can be waited for. How do you call actualSendPush? To wait for the promise you need to actualSendPush().then(() => console.log("I terminated")). Promise.all([]) with one array items is useless. Also try to distill your question to very basics, without specialized code.

Comment: 1. I call actualSendPush by putting it in a Promise.all call, for every user I send the push to. This part work well as I see it is being called for every user.

2. It doesn't terminates, it finished before the .then of the sendToDevice executes.

How do I make actualSendPush wait until sendToDevice's response finishes?